# Database importing problem in Android Pie?

Tags: android, android-database

I’m using Preload Database with multiple Tables with data already present in tables in all tables.
My Error logcat shows “no such table: cake (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: select * from cake at” but actually table and its data are already there.

I have also checked copied database in Phone, it was there but in code it is displaying the error above.

How to solve this problem??

Note : This error occurs only in Google Pixel Phone..

> AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.ebizzapps.swadishtcookingrecipesinhindi, PID: 9060
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ebizzapps.swadishtcookingrecipesinhindi/com.ebizzapps.swadishtcookingrecipesinhindi.DetailRecipe}:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: cake (code 1
>   SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: select * from cake
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>        Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: cake (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: select * from
>   cake
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:903)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:514)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1408)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1347)
>           at com.ebizzapps.swadishtcookingrecipesinhindi.DBHelper.getDatas(DBHelper.java:162)
>           at com.ebizzapps.swadishtcookingrecipesinhindi.DetailRecipe.onCreate(DetailRecipe.java:161)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Comment: it seems like there is notable `cake` according to logcat

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Be sure to read the error message carefully. Also show a minimal example that causes this error.

Comment: Did place your database file on the assets folder under a directory called databases `/assets/databases/database.db`

Comment: i have the databases in assets folder do I need to create databases ?

Comment: I ran into the same issue. My app worked prior to Android P. I know the tables are there but I get this same sqlite exception saying there are not such tables. If you find a solution please message me.

Comment: There's a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50476782/android-p-sqlite-no-such-table-error-after-copying-database-from-assets

Comment: The solution that ended up working for me is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51953955/1172181

Answer (score 3):

See this stackoverflow post: [Android P SQLite Pragma Log](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51953955/1172181).

Disable write ahead logging on your *SQLiteOpenHelper*'s *onOpen* method, like this:

```
@Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onOpen(db);
    db.disableWriteAheadLogging();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a table and name it as "cake".As per the error log

[image]

there is no such table "cake".I think you have forgot to place your database to asset folder.

Thank you

Comment: It will show even if the table exists, this is happening only in pie

Answer (score 0):

From your Error Log.

> no such table: cake (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: select
>   * from cake at

Its mentioned that there is no any table with name `cake` . So before fetching value from table ensure that there is a table with this name already exist in database.

Comment: The error message is misleading. I'm getting the same error but I know the tables exist plus the app worked fine on previous Android versions.