# Why close() is needed when creating database in Android Pie?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using the following code to copy the db from assets

```
public void createDataBase() {
        boolean dbExist = this.checkDataBase();
        if (!dbExist) {
            this.getWritableDatabase();
            **this.close();**
            try {
                this.copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException var3) {
                var3.printStackTrace();
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
           }
    }

}
```

In the above code, it was not working in android P if i dint give **this.close()**. I was unable to create and query the database. But In previous versions it was working fine. I know it is a good practise to close database objects once used. But what is the reason for this behaviour in android Pie?

To get to know this issue in Pie I referred this link but couldn't find the explanation.

[Android P - 'SQLite: No Such Table Error' after copying database from assets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53258585/2007739)

Comment: `code it was not working` how exactly? Also what is `this`?

Comment: My issue was simple. i was unable to create and query the database in android P. when i call this line close() it was working.

Comment: what is `this` in your code?

Comment: it is an SQLiteOpenHelper class.