# Code throws exception table not available after upgrading to Android Pie

Tags: android, android-sqlite

In Android Pie, when I do a db.rawQuery it throws an exception "SQLite Error: No such table available". 
The same piece of code works in Android Oreo and below. I have tried in multiple devices and it fails only in Android Pie.

Code :

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM people";
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null); // Exception happens here
```

I have 3 DB files for my application. The db file which i have problem is downloaded from my server. 
It is downloaded as zip file, unzipped and then i will use it.
On device explorer of the Android Studio, I am able to find the DB inside "/data/data/**packagename**". 
I have downloaded the DB from Android studio file explorer and verified the DB file locally it has all the proper data.

What could be the problem?

Comment: How do You create, upgrade database? Does it have any connection with downloading and reusing database?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50476782

Comment: @deadfish Database is downloaded from internet and it will be replace the existing database