# How to totally fix SQLite "no such table error" on Android 9.0 in Upgrade

Tags: android, sqlite

I have also met sqlite "no such table" error on Android 9.0, I have found there is a similar issue on SO. ([Android P - 'SQLite: No Such Table Error' after copying database from assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50476782/android-p-sqlite-no-such-table-error-after-copying-database-from-assets)).

Base on above link, I tried below solutions 1 and 2.
1) Close connection after read

```
private void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    this.getReadableDatabase();
    this.close(); 
    try {           
        copyDataBase();            
    } catch (IOException e) {           
       throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

2) Disable WAL.

```
@Override
public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Logger.i(TAG, "onConfigure()");
    super.onConfigure(db);
    db.disableWriteAheadLogging();
}

private boolean checkIfDBExists() {
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    return dbFile.exists();
}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

}
```

After that, I found a problem, These solutions are only fine when I remove installed App, and fresh install App.

When I have installed a buggy App with `"no such table error"` on Android **9.0** device, Then I add above fixed code, and install it directly with Android Studio which looks like an App **upgrade** scenario.

In this case, The db file will be over there,  `checkIfDBExists()` will return true, then we will call **`openDataBase()`** instead of `createDataBase()`  The `sqlite "no such table" error` will still happen, So How can I totally fix this issue no matter fresh install or upgrade? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying several times, I have found a solution to fix this issue.
In databases folder, there are some temp files `xxx.db-shm`, `xxx.db-wal`, These files should be generated when enable WAL, so even after we disable WAL later, they are already there which will affect db query.

`So the solution is simple, delete these files when you disable WAL.`