# Android studio "no such table" error when querying sqlite imported database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a SQLite database using [DBBS](https://sqlitebrowser.org/)

> database.db.sql

I then put this file in `src/main/assets/` and load it from `/data/data/PACKAGE_NAME/databases/database.db.sql`.

However, when I try to query the database it throws me the following error

> "no such table"

What I've tried:

- Unistall and reinstall the app
- Create the database again

What am I doing wrong? Is the path of the database correct?

Comment: Which Android version are you testing on? You might have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50476782.

Comment: I'm testing on Android 4.4.2 (KitKat), API 19