# SQLiteException :: no such table : in android Pie 9.0

Tags: android

I m using preload database with multiple tables with data. when I run `db.rawQuery()` method, SqliteException occure ::

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table.

This error occurred in on android pie, all previous working very well. Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Comment: How are you creating database and tables ? If you're copying empty db from Assets to private folder then it won't work in Android 9.

Comment: Try uninstalling your app and installing again

Comment: .sqlite file already preloaded in assets folder and run time this file copied to device data/data/packagename/databases/database.sqlite.

This code working on all android previous version, not wokring in android 9.0 pie

Comment: Yes i knew that's why i asked. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50476782/android-p-sqlite-no-such-table-error-after-copying-database-from-assets) answer and change your code accordingly. This solution worked in all android versions

Comment: Already tried uninstalled and re-install.

Comment: Tried, but not work

 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
                Complete_PATH = database.getPath();
                database.close();
            }
            else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 4.1) {
                Complete_PATH = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            } else {
                
                Complete_PATH = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            }
            database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(Complete_PATH, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);